# Is the HTML5 canvas capable of graphing data for potentially several thousands of data points?

Tags: html, data-visualization

I'm currently using ASP.Net charting to graph a lot of data, potentially tens of thousands of data points on a single graph. All these data points are clickable and have tooltips through a very heavy HTML map. It can handle the load, but sometimes at a very heavy toll to the browser. I'm wondering if there's a better solution with the HTML5 canvas?

Are there any tools out there for graphing data through HTML5 canvas? Something that would maintain a hover tooltip and click events on each data point would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas can handle as many data points as you want, for the simple reason that once you paint something on canvas, it just becomes part of the raster image, not saved as a separate piece of data.

However, for your tooltip functionality you would need to implement other functions for figuring out where in the canvas the mouse clicked -- i.e., you'd have to keep track of the data locations in memory, and implement a click function that searches that data structure to figure out which tooltip to display.

A number of people have played around with using D3 methods (which usually are linked to DOM SVG elements) to figure out a graphical layout based on data, and then paint that layout to canvas instead of adding to the DOM.

[Forum discussion here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/d3-js/canvas|sort%3adate/d3-js/z6D5yOoC5-4/cgbvdpcXUTEJ).